# Ubuntu gets stuck loading account

Tags: 16.04, unity, lightdm, login-screen

Ubnutu gets stuck while loading my account. You can see the wallpaper and move the mouse. In the corner you can see ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I am able to start a tty shell with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>. I think it might be a problem with starting unity I've tried to reinstall unity but it just does the same thing when I reboot and try to log on.

Someone please help

Comment: Go into another tty, using ctrl+alt+f1, create a new user... see if it's happen for new user too.

Comment: Yes the same thing happens to my alternate user and as well as the guest session. But when I make a new user and try to login it try's to log me in then takes me back to the login screen.